# creating demo version of c# windows application

Tags: c#

I have coded a software which is a windows application in c#. 
I wish to create a demo version of my software. How can I use a timer so that the installed software runs for a definate period of time ?
Also is it possible that even if the user machine is formatted, the application wont install after my preset time is exhausted  ?

Comment: instead of giving a -1 it would be great if you could give an answer. !

Comment: I would suggest doing some research into the nature of what you want to do - there seems to be a lot you'll need to understand that a simple answer here won't provided for you (in the long run). Go have a try and come back with a specific problem to solve, if you find one.

Comment: You cannot ask for a complete solution here. Please specify a concrete problem and we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I use a timer so that the installed software runs for a
>   definite period of time ?

You create your own hashing function which generates license key, here one of the components of the key is a final day.  So you save that key into a file, and on every start-up check the value present inside it against the actual value of date on PC.

Pro:   Easy to implement and put in production

Cons:  Easy to hack. Just enough to cheat the DateTime settings of OS.

*Another option*: you can use some licensing software:

Look here on possible options: [Licensing System for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132943/licensing-system-for-net)

*Another again*: some web service where you check the data (avoid client side data cheating)

*Another again*: is limit demo version not on time, but on functionality (limited features are available, you can save data on disk limited amount of time, you can run application limited times... and so  on)

> Also is it possible that even if the user machine is formatted, the
>   application wont install after my pre-set time is exhausted ?

no, it's not possible, as formatting means data complete erase.

Comment: +1. I would write that key to the Registry instead, much harder to hack (people can easily delete the file by uninstalling/reinstalling). Also, maybe keep track of how long the software was used and subtract the value from the key, to ensure that people can not cheat with system time.

Comment: @Nolonar: hacking, in means of tricking data, is not related, in this case, to a *place* where the key is, but to *data* it relays on. If client is expirienced with PCs, he can potentially try to cheat the DateTime and it will break license whatever it's: a hidden file, or registry entry.

Comment: @Nolonar - Its trivial to figure out what a program expects in a in the registery to avoid demo functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to connect the application to a server-side registration mechanism (which I wouldn't recommend), then you can place a value in the Registry that you use to determine when the trial started. Subtract that value from the current date and time when the application is loaded and you'll be able to determine when it should stop. **However, this is not safe from a format or hacking.**

My recommended solution is to for server-side registration of the trial software during the first load. This will allow you to ensure that even if they reformatted the drive they couldn't get past the registration. Though this still isn't fool proof because they could register under many aliases, it's at least a lot more trouble. **One remaining issue with this idea** is what happens if they aren't connected to the internet? Are you going to stop them from using the application? You could couple this idea with the first one and leverage the Registry if they don't have an internet connection.

Either way, preventing people from hacking your registration process is difficult at best. Microsoft has struggled with it since their inception.